# remove &nbsp; from String in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, whitespace

I have inserted a option in Dorpdown as follows

```
<option>إختر&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
```

When I select this text from server side on any event I get this value
"إختر       ‎"

Now I want to replace this white space in the string. I have tried replace method of String class. But its not working.

```
str = str.replace("&nbsp;","")
```

Plz suggest

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual code?

Comment: `its not working` <-- please specify **how** - what is the result you got, and you expected to see instead. We need to know your sample input and output for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do first is decode the HTML, such that text like `&nbsp;` but also `&amp;` are converted to their textual counterparts (`" "` and `"&"`). You can do this with: [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Next you can use [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove leading and tailing spaces.

Example:

```
string s = "إختر&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
string r = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s).Trim();
```

Or the VB.NET equivalent:

```
Dim s As String = "إختر&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
Dim r As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s).Trim()
```

Evidently you can try to convert `&nbsp;` to spaces yourself. But there are examples where it is not that evident and your transcoder can get confused or decode strings the wrong way. Furthermore if in the future the people at W3C change their minds about how to encode text in HTML/XML, then your program will still work.

`String.Trim` will remove all kinds of [white-space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) including spaces, new lines, tabs, carriage returns, etc. If you only want to remove spaces, you can use: `.Trim(' ')`. Then you specify only to remove the given list of characters (here only `' '`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks. It's a bit hard (for non-native English speakers) to distinguish between different names of whitespace. And after all it's only by standards that ASCII code 32 is a space. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove leading or trailing white-spaces from a string you just need to use [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx), but you have to re-assign the return value to the variable since strings are immutable:

```
string text = "إختر       ‎";
text = text.Trim();
```

Note that you can also use `TrimEnd` in this case.

If you want to remove only space characters(not also tabs or new-line characters which are also white-spaces) use:

```
text = text.Trim(' ');
```

If you instead want to remove all spaces from a string you could do:

```
text = text.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(strResponseData).trim()  I tried this.. still no positive result

Comment: @Pramod: have you assigned the return value of `String.Trim` to your string variable as i've mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did.  in all the function I am assigning the result to my string

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your code is something like this

```
Dim str As String = "إختر&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
str.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
```

But actually you should

```
Dim str As String = "إختر&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
str = str.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
```

Comment: I am storing the value and then watching it. Its not removing white space after replace method

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar problem. 
It turns out, that this nbsp character is Chr(160) from the ASCII table. Thus, something like this is quite meaningful, for all the cases. It works, on a selected area:

```
Public Sub remove_space_in_string()

    Dim r_range As Range

    For Each r_range In Selection
        r_range = Trim(r_range)
        r_range = Replace(r_range, vbTab, "")
        r_range = Replace(r_range, " ", "")
        r_range = Replace(r_range, Chr(160), "")
    Next r_range
End Sub
```